# Map both arrays and copy result in new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 array1 = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "aaa",
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "bbb"
      },
{
        "id": 5,
        "name": "ccc"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "ddd"
      },
{
        "id": 8,
        "name": "eee"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "fff"
      }]

array2 = [ 5, 6, 8 ,12]
```

Resulting Array = `[ {name: "ccc"}, {name: "ddd"} , {name: "eee"}, {name: "fff"} ]`

I am looking to map both arrays to get matching id numbers and get copy the names in the resulting arrray but I didn't succeed. Can you please suggest me how to do it?

Thank you

Comment: You can't have `name:value` pairs in an array, that's only allowed in objects.

Comment: Loop through `array1`. Test if `element.id` is in `array2`. If it is, push `{name: element.name}` into the resulting array.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited the question

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? Do you know how to loop over an array? Do you know how to test if a value is in an array? Do you know how to push something into the result array? If you answer yes to all these questions, just put them all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following. Basically, you're filtering the first array based on whether or not the id exists in the 2nd array and then mapping it back by only selecting the key(s) you want.

```
var resultArray = array1.filter(function(arr) {
    return array2.indexOf(arr.id) !== -1;
}).map(function(item) {
    return {
        name: item.name
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's turn `array1` into an object first, that maps ids to the corresponding objects:

```
var idMap = {}
array1.forEach(function(element) {
    idMap[element.id] = element
})
```

You can then get the result you want by doing

```
var result = array2.map(function(id) {
    return idMap[id]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```js
array1 = [{"id": 1,"name": "aaa"},{"id": 2,"name": "bbb"},{"id": 5,"name": "ccc"},{"id": 6,"name": "ddd"},{"id": 8,"name": "eee"},{"id": 12,"name": "fff"}] ;

array2 = [ 5, 6, 8 ,12];

var result = array1.filter(item => array2.includes(item.id)).map(({id,name}) => ({name}));

console.log( result );
```